# file_get_contents() acting up on facebook api

Tags: php, facebook

```
file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: SSL: Connection reset by peer in
```

on

```
file_get_contents("https://api.facebook.com/method/events.invite?eid=" .  $eid . "&uids=" . json_encode($uids) . "&access_token=" . $facebook->getAccessToken())
```

It invites users friends which they selected to the event, `however` i'm getting the error at the top of this post.  Tested with `cURL`, same error.

TESTED

I went back and tested some things with cURL

```
$url = "https://api.facebook.com/method/events.invite?eid=157437064317827&uids=" . json_encode($uids) . "&access_token=" . $facebook->getAccessToken();

$url2 = urlencode($url);
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$data = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));
curl_close($ch);`
```

Getting errors with that: Couldn't resolve host 'https%3A%2F%2Fapi.facebook.com...

Comment: What if you use http instead? Is PHP compiled with OpenSSH support? I remember I faced this problem before but I can't recall exactly what I've done.

Comment: Tried http, exact same error.  I'm messing around with cURL again.  Any experience with that will be helpful :)

Comment: is your domain supporting OpenSSH?

Comment: I use hostgator, and i believe they enabled my shell stuff a while back so i can upload a HUGE database.  (kind of new to messing with that).

Comment: is https a registered php stream? is ssl a registered stream socket transport?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the Graph API, rather than the deprecated API?

You could instead call:

```
$event_id = "EVENT_ID";
$user_ids = "ID1,ID2,ID3"; // this can be populated however, but that's the syntax
$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$event_id}/invited/{$user_ids}";
$graph_contents = file_get_contents($graph_url);
$data = json_decode($graph_contents);
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should never URLencode a full URL. You should URLencode specific portions of a URL (i.e. the query parameter names and values), but the whole URL being URL-encoded will cause your code to fail, since the parts of the URL won't be properly separated.